# Filter list by start and end tokens

Tags: haskell

Say I have a list of strings:

```
let listA = ["hello", "start", "stuff", "end", "boo"]
```

I want to filter this list according to start and end tokens `"start"` and `"end"`. So my end result should be:

```
["start", "stuff", "end"]
```

I need a function `filterByTokens` that will do this. This is what I have so far but I'm hitting a wall:

```
slice :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
slice _ _ [] = []
slice from to list = take (to - from + 1) rest
    where rest = drop from list

filterByTokens :: a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
filterByTokens start end list = 
    sIndex = elemIndex start list
    eIndex = elemIndex end list
    slice sIndex eIndex list
```

`filterRange` will work on a single block, but what if I have multiple? Also, `elemIndex` returns a `Maybe` type so how do I convert this to an `Int`? Please help.

**UPDATE**

I've updated my function to `take` recursively but I'm still hitting a wall:

```
takeBetween :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
takeBetween _ _ [] = []
takeBetween start end (x:xs)
    | x == start    = takeIt True (x:xs)
    | x == end      = takeIt False (x:xs)
    | otherwise     = takeIt _ (x:xs)
    where takeIt status
        | status = x : takeBetween start end xs
        | otherwise = takeBetween start end xs
```

But I can't pass in a `_` for the status boolean. Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

**NOTE**

If there are multiple start stop pairs the resulting list should be made up of whatever is between each of them. For example:

`["x","start","y","stop","z","start","w","stop"]` should return `["start", "y", "stop", "start", "w", "stop"]`

If a stop token is before a start token it is ignored.

`["stop","x","start","y","stop"]` returns `["start", "y", "stop"]`

Ideally only the first start and the first stop tokens will have value:

`["start","x","start","y","stop","stop"]` returns `["start", "x", "start", "y", "stop"]`

`["start","x","start","y","stop"]` returns `["start", "x", "start", "y", "stop"]`

**UPDATE 2**

I've also tried a simpler approach using just a drop, to no avail:

```
takeByToken :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
takeByToken start end (x:xs) = dropWhile (\x -> not $ x == start) xs
```

Please help me figure this out.

**Update 3**

With much help from [dfeuer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1477667/dfeuer) I came up with this solution:

```
data Status = Between | NotBetween
takeBetweens :: [String] -> [String]
takeBetweens = takeBetweens' NotBetween

takeBetweens' :: Status -> String -> String -> [String] -> [String]
takeBetweens' _ _ _ [] = []
takeBetweens' NotBetween s e (x : xs)
    | s == x = x : takeBetweens' Between s e xs
    | otherwise = takeBetweens' NotBetween s e xs
takeBetweens' Between s e (x : xs)
    | e == x = x : takeBetweens' NotBetween s e xs
    | otherwise = x : takeBetweens' Between s e xs
```

However, this solution still requires me to use 2 functions. I've tried to include the helper `takeBetweens'` function in a `where` clause but am running into syntax errors (noob i know).

```
data Status = Between | NotBetween

takeBetweens :: [String] -> [String]
takeBetweens = takeBetweens' NotBetween "start" "end"
    where takeBetweens' _ _ _ [] = []
    takeBetweens' NotBetween s e (x : xs)
        | s == x = x : takeBetweens' Between s e xs
        | otherwise = takeBetweens' NotBetween s e xs
    takeBetweens' Between s e (x : xs)
        | e == x = x : takeBetweens' NotBetween s e xs
        | otherwise = x : takeBetweens' Between s e xs



test.hs:5:9: parse error on input ‘takeBetweens'’
```

How do I include the helper function in a `where` clause?

Comment: Exactly what do you want the result to look like when there are multiple start/stop pairs? What do you want to happen when pairs are mismatched? There are several reasonable answers to each of these questions.

Comment: `dropWhile, takeWhile` can be useful here. Drop everything until you find the start, and then take everything until you find the end.

Comment: Your update does not address either of my questions. What should I get from `["x","start","y","stop","z","start","w","stop"]`? What should I get from `["stop","x","start","y","stop"]` and from `["start","x","start","y","stop","stop"]` and from `["start","x","start","y","stop"]`?

Comment: @dfeuer I've updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: So you're saying the result for your original `listA` example should actually be `["stuff"]`, rather than `["start", "stuff", "stop"]` as you wrote in your question?

Comment: @dfeuer Sorry, the results should be wrapped by the tokens. I've updated the question.

Comment: The approach I outlined in my answer should be pretty easy for you to complete without using *any* library functions whatsoever. Just pattern matching and data constructors. If you want to use library functions, your output format will likely make that a bit tricky. The ones I'd suggest looking at are `break` and `span`, but I wouldn't personally bother; the explicit state machine will be easier.

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake was in thinking about indices. Don't! Lists are not arrays, and pretending they are will lead to code that is both complicated and slow.

I suggest you use a helper function:

```
data Status = NotBetween | Between

takeBetweens' :: Status -> [String] -> [String]
```

The idea is that `takeBetweens' NotBetween s` should look for a `"start"` dropping everything on the way, then call itself with `Between` while `takeBetweens Between s` should grab everything till it sees `"stop"` then call itself with `NotBetween`.

I urge you to write the function without ever using a number.

#### A bigger hint

```
takeBetweens :: [String] -> [String]
takeBetweens = takeBetweens' NotBetween

takeBetweens' :: Status -> [String] -> [String]
takeBetweens' _ [] = ?
takeBetweens' NotBetween ("start" : xs) = ?
takeBetweens' NotBetween (x : xs) = ?
takeBetweens' Between ("stop" : xs) = ?
takeBetweens' Between (x : xs) = ?
```

Can you see how this is basically a state machine? Can you see when and how to change state?

Comment: `I urge you to write the function without ever using a number.` This is the ideal scenario. I don't know how to do this without storing the current state of the parser as a flag. OOP has taken over my brain =/...

Comment: @dopatraman, the helper function I suggested is one of the functional approaches to "storing the current state of the parser as a flag". In a more general situation, you'd likely need a different technique to make the parser state available to the various parser pieces, but that's not necessary here.

Comment: i updated my answer... could use your help figuring this out.

Comment: Thank you very much for your update.  I manage to solve the problem, but have one final question. I've added it to the original post. How do I include the helper function `takeBetweens'` in a `where` clause? I'd rather do that than use two separate functions.

Answer (score 2):

This may give you an idea...

```
Prelude> let f x = reverse . dropWhile (/=x)                                                                          
Prelude> let between s e = f e . f s
Prelude> between 3 5 [1..10]
[3,4,5]
```

obviously has no error handling, what should happen if there is no end specified?